# On a certain bijection of the multiplicative group modulo prime $p=2^k+1$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Let:

$G=\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ be the multiplicative group of integers modulo prime $p=2^k+1$;

$v_2(a)$ be the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $a$;

$\mu(a)=\max\{j\in[0,k]\ |\ x^{2^j} \equiv a\}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{G}$;

$A_i = \{a\in\mathbb{G}\ |\ v_2(a)=i\}$;

$B_i = \{a\in\mathbb{G}\ |\ \mu(a)=i\}$.

Now, couple questions:

> 1. Prove that $a$-powers of the elements of $G$ are exactly $2^{v_2(a)}$-powers of the elements of $G$.

I prove this by introducing two sub-groups $G_1=\{x^a,x\in G\}$ and $G_2=\{x^{2^{v_2(a)}},x\in G\}$ and showing that $G_1\subseteq G_2$ and $G_2\subseteq G_1$. *But could there be less laborious and more intuitive proof, which is often the case with simpler problems in number theory?*

> 2. Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$ and $f$ be a map from $G$ to itself that sends $x$ to $g^x$ modulo $p$. Prove that $f$ is a bijection that sends $A_i$ to $B_i$ for each $i\in\{0,\ldots,k\}$.

This one I can't formally prove at all...

Comment: It would really help to clean up the notation in this post: $a$ is being used for multiple things simultaneously; and the map $a\mapsto g^a$ doesn't make sense for an abstract group to itself—perhaps it should be a map from $\{1,\dots,p-1\}$ to $\mathbb G$.

Comment: As for your first question, here's a lemma: if $b$ is an odd number, prove that the map $x\mapsto x^b$ is a bijection on $G$, and a bijection on every subgroup of $G$ when restricted to that subgroup. Then apply with $b$ chosen so that $a=2^{\nu_2(a)}b$.

Comment: @GregMartin By $G$ I actually mean $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$. But I'll make it explicit.